# How to select the next number in a loop?

Tags: php, loops, math, element

The function for the primes is clear, so I omitted it.

```
$a=10;
$z=30;
for($prime = $a; $prime<$z; $prime++)
{ if
(Prim($prime) == TRUE)
{  echo $prime."<br/>";}}
```

Now I want to select the next term of the sequence as well, in order to perform an operation between the variable `$prime` and `$next_prime`, as long as the loop goes on - like for example:

```
$prime_gap=bcsub($next_prime, $prime);
```

Whatever solutions I find and I try, it's never the proper one. It's surely very simple but I am already desperate.

Comment: What language is that code in?

Comment: It's PHP, of course  - the only code I know  (besides html of course)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start by creating a `next_prime()` function. Like this, for example:

```php
function next_prime($n) {
    do {
        $n++;
    } while (!Prim($n));
    return $n;
}
```

Then you can refactor your code quite easily:

```php
$a=10;
$z=30;
for ($p1=next_prime($a),$p2=next_prime($p1); $p2<$z; $p1=$p2,$p2=next_prime($p2)) {
    if (some_function($p1, $p2)) {
        echo "I like $p1 and $p2\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi all!

It looks magnificent, thank you very much. 

Yes, I want to keep it simple because I need this kind of solution repeatedly, for other problems as well. Actually I wonder that there is no ready-made function for it in php.net, only for arrays the function next().

When I'm ready with it I will show it to you.

Comment: @HdL: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition, accept the best answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` I add in the for loop is not so nice, but if you want something simple and easy to understand, you can still use it (I switch the name from $prime & $next_prime to $prime & $previous_prime, I think it makes more sense)

```
$a=10;
$z=30;
$previous_prime = 0;

for($prime = $a; $prime<$z; $prime++)
{ 
  if (Prim($prime) == TRUE)
  {  
     echo $prime."<br/>";
     if ($previous_prime == 0) {
        $previous_prime = $prime
     } else 
     {
        $prime_gap = $prime - $previous_prime;
        $previous_prime = $prime;
     }
  }
}
```